# How can I use localized runtime framework resources in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, localization, flex4, flash-builder

By default, Flex uses signed .swz files to hold the Flex Framework classes.  I noticed that under Adobe Flash Builder 4 > sdks > [version] > frameworks > locale > [locale] there are multiple languages supported.

en_US
en_GB
zh_CN
etc etc

The files in these directories vary in that they contain a "_rb.swc" at the end of each file.  Files include datavisualization_rb.swc, spark_rb.swc, framework_rb.swc, etc etc.  These are different from the rsls signed framework resources stored as .swz in framework .rsls.  Since localized signed versions of the framework don't appear to be available, can I use these locale > [LOCALE] .swc versions instead as RUNTIME SHARED RESOURCES?

**I DON'T want to compile different versions of my app for each locale**, rather want to link the localized framework resource libraries at runtime.  It would be nice to have the contents of the sdks > [VERSION] > frameworks > locale directory copied into my bin-debug/bin-release folder when I build my app.

Is this possible?  How would I set this up in Flash Builder 4?

My assumption (I know about assumptions) is that there is a way to set up the Flex Build Path or supply compiler options that would cause all of the locales stored in the locales > [LOCALE] folder to be included into the bin-debug/bin-release of the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [ResourceManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3a.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6119c-7fef) to do it on runtime, it's easy enough.